# jQuery tablesorter: custom html image tag sorter/parser

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using the [jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com). It seems to be working fine except that it can't sort rows with image tags as their content. I want to implement something that just sorts by the src attribute of the image tag. I have tried a number of things but can't seem to get it to work.

### Problems:

- The plugin does not detect my image columns with the image parser, it detects it as using the `digit` parser, so I have to specify the image parser manually.
- The `s` argument being passed to the `format` function of my parser seems to be blank/null/undefined (something like that, I can't tell).

### Code:

JavaScript:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'image', 
    is: function(s) {
        //i think this works
        return /^<img(.*)>$/.test(s);
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        //neither of these work
        return $(s).attr('src').toLowerCase();
        return s.match(/src="(.*)"/);
    },
    type: 'text' 
}); 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>             
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>text column</th> 
            <th class="{sorter: 'image'}">image column</th>  
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>a</td> 
            <td><img src="d.gif"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>b</td> 
            <td><img src="c.gif"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>c</td> 
            <td><img src="b.gif"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>d</td> 
            <td><img src="a.gif"></td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way given your markup would be to scrap the custom parser and do the following.

```
$("table").tablesorter({
     textExtraction:function(s){
        var $el = $(s),
        $img = $el.find('img');
        return $img.length ? $img[0].src : $el.text();
     }  
});
```

Comment: the fact that you are using the `$el` variable on the same line as you are assigning it (separated by a comma) is sort of blowing my mind right now. But it works! And it solves my immediate problem for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue involves tablesorter's use of innerHTML when it should be using innerText:
[jquery tablesorter custom parser - innerHTML vs. innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365237/jquery-tablesorter-custom-parser-innerhtml-vs-innertext)